# Base de Dados Access, Duplicação de Registos

Tags: validação, microsoft-access, restrição-único

Numa BD Access com campos ID (Numeração automática), FUNCIONÁRIO, DATA, QUANTIDADE, os dados são recolhidos diariamente (numa única mensagem) via Outlook. Portanto, é possível evitar que um mesmo funcionário tenha dois registos na BD com mesma data? Por favor, se possível, preciso aprender, ajudam-me. 
É que precisa-se evitar que o funcionário envia uma mesma mensagem duas vezes ou mais. Por ex.:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O campo funcionário é chave estrangeira (FK)?

Comment: Não é chave estrangeira, mas importa dizer que nesse campo existe uma relação com outra tabela na qual também não é Chave mas está indexado com duplicação não autorizada. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o código abaixo:

ALTER TABLE [sua_tabela] ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_registro UNIQUE ([FUNCIONÁRIO], [DATA])

Comment: Desculpa caríssimo @fba_pereira onde posso colocar esse código? na "Regra de validação" ou aonde? Perdoa a minha ingenuidade é que só um novato nessa matéria. Obrigado!